# Use of drawable vectors SDK < 21: Binary XML file line #68: Error inflating class <unknown> invalid drawable tag vector

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-drawable, android-appcompat

I'm using android studio 3.1.2 on Linux, **with the following setup**:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 19
Gradle version: 4.4
Android plugin version: 3.1.2
```

**My project uses the following dependencies:**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
```

**On pre Lollipop devices - SDK < 21 , I'm getting the following exception:**

```js
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ro.aripisprecer.radiocrestin/ro.aripisprecer.radiocrestin.HomeScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #68: Error inflating class <unknown>

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #68: Error inflating class <unknown>

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:670) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                         at ro.aripisprecer.radiocrestin.PlayRadio.onCreateView(PlayRadio.java:350) 
                         at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700) 
                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890) 
                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062) 
                         at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684) 
                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447) 
                         at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                      
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_share_black_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f08009b
                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2101)
                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                         at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
                         at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3484)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595) 
                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:670) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                         at ro.aripisprecer.radiocrestin.PlayRadio.onCreateView(PlayRadio.java:350) 
                         at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700) 
                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890) 
                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062) 
                         at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684) 
                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447) 
                         at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 

Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
                         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
                         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2097)
                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
                         at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554) 
                         at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3484) 
                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595) 
                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:670) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                         at ro.aripisprecer.radiocrestin.PlayRadio.onCreateView(PlayRadio.java:350) 
                         at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700) 
                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890) 
                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062) 
                         at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684) 
                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447) 
                         at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have followed other suggestions and replaced:

1. `android:src` to `app:srcCompat`,
2. included `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in the *build.gradle*, and
3. `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)`
   in the *public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity{*

But this didn't solved my problem.

**See a snippet from my homescreen_layout.xml starting from line #68**

```
 <View
    android:layout_width="14dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/music_image"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/music_image" />
```

**And this is the content of the ic_share_black_24dp.xml file:**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:width="14dp"
android:height="14dp"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:viewportWidth="24.0"
tools:ignore="VectorRaster">

<path
    android:fillColor="@color/red_color_toolbar"
    android:pathData="M18,16.08c-0.76,0 -1.44,0.3 -1.96,0.77L8.91,12.7c0.05,-0.23 0.09,-0.46 0.09,-0.7s-0.04,-0.47 -0.09,-0.7l7.05,-4.11c0.54,0.5 1.25,0.81 2.04,0.81 1.66,0 3,-1.34 3,-3s-1.34,-3 -3,-3 -3,1.34 -3,3c0,0.24 0.04,0.47 0.09,0.7L8.04,9.81C7.5,9.31 6.79,9 6,9c-1.66,0 -3,1.34 -3,3s1.34,3 3,3c0.79,0 1.5,-0.31 2.04,-0.81l7.12,4.16c-0.05,0.21 -0.08,0.43 -0.08,0.65 0,1.61 1.31,2.92 2.92,2.92 1.61,0 2.92,-1.31 2.92,-2.92s-1.31,-2.92 -2.92,-2.92z" />
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you comment out that class `Binary XML file line #68` Does your project run?

Comment: If i comment out the class starting at the line #68 , it moves to the next one, line #128:

<ImageButton
.....
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/report_btn_draw"


if i comment every imagebutton i get a null ponter exception 
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ro.aripisprecer.radiocrestin/ro.aripisprecer.radiocrestin.HomeScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Okay. I didn't noticed this. Please change your `targetSdkVersion 19` to 27 and download latest build tool version `27.0.3` and check it on emulator API 17, (not on API 19, it has some unresolved bugs) See, if that works.

Comment: @RohitSharma it is the same error. Could it be that the exceptions comes from somewhere else and not from this xml file?

Answer (score 0):

**2 errors are quite evident from your Logcat**

```
 1. Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_share_black_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f08009b
 2. Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
```

If after upgrade also, you are encountering the same error, then

Try it one by one, whatever works.

- Make sure your naming matches since it is not able to find it, I would suggest you to:

  a. `Invalidate Caches/Restart`,

  b. if not, **delete** `.idea` & `.gradle` from your project location

  c. if not, **delete** the resource, **clean** the project and **recreate** the resource again
- Make sure your `ic_share_black_24dp` is not used anywhere else in the project, i.e. left drawer panel (navigation menu) & right panel (navigation menu), if it is then rename one of the resource

---

**Also, try it with this vector resource**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M18,16.08c-0.76,0 -1.44,0.3 -1.96,0.77L8.91,12.7c0.05,-0.23 0.09,-0.46 0.09,-0.7s-0.04,-0.47 -0.09,-0.7l7.05,-4.11c0.54,0.5 1.25,0.81 2.04,0.81 1.66,0 3,-1.34 3,-3s-1.34,-3 -3,-3 -3,1.34 -3,3c0,0.24 0.04,0.47 0.09,0.7L8.04,9.81C7.5,9.31 6.79,9 6,9c-1.66,0 -3,1.34 -3,3s1.34,3 3,3c0.79,0 1.5,-0.31 2.04,-0.81l7.12,4.16c-0.05,0.21 -0.08,0.43 -0.08,0.65 0,1.61 1.31,2.92 2.92,2.92 1.61,0 2.92,-1.31 2.92,-2.92s-1.31,-2.92 -2.92,-2.92z"/>
</vector>
```

**Edit: In your View tag, please change this:**

`android:background="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"`

to this:

`app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"`

Comment: I have followed every step as you described and it seams it coud find the resource, but the problem is with the "vector" tag. I have uploaded the full debug trace, the xml resource and the home screen layout on google drive. You can have a look and maybe you could find something. Please have a look here: 
  
 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12Obj7dY8yxVAf6YLGEmA4lU35TLSb7mm?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks Marius. Is it also possible to share the whole project, so that I can test it tomorrow.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I am not allowed to share the whole app. Would it be possible for you to connect remotely to my computer and check it live?

Comment: Sure thing. AnyDesk?

Comment: Edited the answer. :)

Comment: Should I send you the ID here or as a text file on Google drive?

Comment: Hey, please see the document from the google drive. There is my id. I am online, just text me on skype. Thank you!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  I tried replacing `android:background` with `app:srcCompat` which stopped the crashes, however now the views look completely wrong...